# Error to generate micro-go code - --go_out: protoc-gen-go: unknown plugin "micro"

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I have to generate bin folder into my project through a makefile, but when i type 'make build' at the directory where makefile is, protoc-gen-go returns an error to me:

```
--go_out: protoc-gen-go: unknown plugin "micro"
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

the build block:

```
protoc -I. --go_out=plugins=micro:$(shell pwd) \
    proto/version/version.proto
```

micro was installed at `/Users/wendelrios/bin/micro`

Can someone explain to me whats wrong and whats happening?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/asim/protoc-gen-micro#errors)? Have you tried [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=protoc-gen-go%3A+unknown+plugin+%22micro%22)? What were the results of researching what it yields?

Comment: the first link was helpful, because protoc wasnt in /go/bin, so i created a link to point, but the error keep going

Answer (score 0):

I got it. `protoc`, `protoc-gen-go` and `protoc-gen-micro` should be in `/Users/user_name/go/bin` The command below worked for me:

```
protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-go=/Users/wendelrios/go/bin/protoc-gen-go --plugin=protoc-gen-micro=/Users/wendelrios/go/bin/protoc-gen-micro -I. --micro_out=. --go_out=. proto/version/version.proto
```